# Asynchronous synchronisation

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have 2 async tasks:

1. I'm getting user's location;
2. I'm getting list of events from my API using Retrofit;

**My question:** How do I set an action only after I get successful result from both methods?
Thank you.

Comment: please post your code in your question as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make 2 asynctasks.

2) in the first asynctask get users location in `doInBackground()` and then in `onPostExecute()` start the second asynctask.

3) in the second asynctask  get events from api in `doInBackground()`.

4) then in the `onPostExecute()` of second asynctask you do what ever you want do (because both tasks are finished).

[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) they say asyncTask is deprecated so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use AsyncTask as it's now deprecated according to [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

I recommend you to use Coroutines for consuming you API, it's more simple than AsnycTask and you gonna write less code.

Check the official documentation of the coroutines.
Also, check [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines#parallel) which will serve your need.

If you still using Java, you can use RXjava2 for your async network calls. check [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/rxjava-2-parallel-multiple-network-call-made-easy-1e1f14163eef) would also serve your need.